# Google API referrer restriction not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I created a Google Geocoding API key with domain referrer restrictions.

For testing my website locally, I modified the `/etc/hosts` file on my laptop so that local.ropewiki.com points to 127.0.0.1.  But this isn't working, I get this error from Google API:

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error
Your site URL to be authorized: http://local.ropewiki.com/Location
```

If I remove the referrer restriction then it works fine.  Does Google somehow know that this isn't a real domain?

[image]